# Structured Exception Handling and MinGW

Tags: c, mingw, mingw-w64, mingw32, seh

I want to catch a system exception "ACCESS_VIOLATION" from my native code, in MS VS I do this:

```c
#define PROTECTED_START() __try { \
#define PROTECTED_END(ONERR) } __except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) {ONERR;}
```

What is the equivalent in mingw?

I tried this and is not working:

```c
#define PROTECTED_START() __try1(EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION) { \
#define PROTECTED_END(ONERR) } __except1 { ONERR; }
```